# How to create Object[][] from ArrayList<Object[]> in java

Tags: java, arrays, collections

i have a `ArrayList` with ObjectArrays like this:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> objectList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

i would like to convert it to:

```
Object[][] objectListAsArray = ...
```

My first thought was to convert the list with objectArrays to an array:

```
objectList.toArray()
```

... but this will only return a single `Object[]`. Can someone help me to find a solution?

Regards 
mmm...

Comment: Can I ask why you would need an array of object arrays? It's a strange thing that I haven't seen used often. I've only seen multi-dim arrays for primitive etc, for math reasons. Using objects this way is odd at best. Perhaps there is a nicer solution to a bigger problem

Comment: Hi Java Drinker, sorry for the delayed answer. I need the multi-dimensional object array for [TestNGs](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) data provider.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Object[][] array = list.toArray(new Object[list.size()][]);
```

As Peter noted, your `Object[]` will be shared between the list and the array. If you want different arrays, you'd have to iterate the list and copy the arrays.

Comment: Yes, this is the one. You can even remove `maxArraySize`: `list.toArray(new Object[list.size()][])`

Comment: toArray() does a shallow copy of the ArrayList.

Comment: @Bozho, Which means the `Object[]` remain the same.

Comment: @Bozho, but it does make creating `[maxArraySize]` redundant. It may make the code appear to be doing something its not.

Answer (score 3):

Just try that:

```
Object[][] objectListAsArray = objectList.toArray(new Object[0][]);
```

Comment: No, you have to provide a size for the "rows" in the 2D array. This does not compile (why the upvotes?!).

Comment: @jfpoilpret - doesn't compile - good idea but small mistake (unfortunately)

Comment: Oops, sorry for putting the 0 in the wrong index, I almost never use arrays of arrays (which i think is a good practice anyway).

Comment: @jfpoilpret - (then you should edit and correct your answer ;) )

Comment: @Bart Kiers maybe the upvotes are because the original answer was a big step in the right direction, not necessarily THE right answer.

Comment: @jfpoilpret, yeah, maybe. But I just found it strange that your answer received more upvotes than Bozho's, while yours wouldn't even compile. (I removed my down-vote now that you fixed it, btw)